# ¿Como funciona NSFetchedResultsController y su delegate?

Tags: ios, swift

Como bien dice la pregunta, quiero saber como funciona `NSFetchedResultsController` y porque usar los métodos del delegate en vez de `tableView.reloadData`.

Los estoy usando para armar una `TableView` pero no anda para nada bien, al cargar la app no me muestra las entidades en cada `cell` y al agregar una nueva entidad, se lagea y ni se muestran las lineas de las celdas.

Dejo el proyecto en dropbox:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4fo8h7c4q21t16h/AAAVYOB1rP3zDrq3hwjKG8SWa?dl=0

y un poco del código debajo.

```
class TableViewController : UITableViewController, AddCourseViewControllerDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext!

    //Este objeto se encarga de integrar un fetchRequest con la ViewController.
    lazy var fetchedResultController : NSFetchedResultsController = {//Es un closure que devuelve un objeto.
        () -> NSFetchedResultsController in

        let fetch = NSFetchRequest()
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Course", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "author", ascending: true)

        fetch.entity = entity
        fetch.sortDescriptors = [sort]

        let fetchedResult : NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetch, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "author", cacheName: nil)

        fetchedResult.delegate = self

        return fetchedResult
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        do {
            try fetchedResultController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }


    }

    func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }


    //Mark: - NSFetchedResultController delegate methods

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        switch type {
        case .Delete:
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            break;
        case .Insert:
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                break;
        case .Move:
            tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, toIndexPath: newIndexPath!)
                break;
        case .Update:
            let curso = controller.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! Course
            let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)
            cell?.textLabel?.text = curso.title
            cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = curso.author
                break;
        }

    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

        switch type {
        case .Insert:
            let set = NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex)
            tableView.insertSections(set, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            break;
        case .Delete:
            let set = NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex)
            tableView.deleteSections(set, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }



    }

    //MARK: - TableView dataSource

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return fetchedResultController.sections!.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fetchedResultController.sections![section].numberOfObjects
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")!

        let course : Course = (fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects![indexPath.row]) as! Course

        cell.textLabel!.text = course.title
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = course.author

        return cell
    }


    private func getFetchedController() -> NSFetchedResultsController {
        let fetch = NSFetchRequest()
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Course", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "author", ascending: true)

        fetch.entity = entity
        fetch.sortDescriptors = [sort]

        let fetchedResult = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetch, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "author", cacheName: nil)

        return fetchedResult
    }


    //MARK: - AddCourseDelegate

    func addCourseViewControllerDidSave() {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error al guardar el curso.")
        }
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func addCourseViewControllerDidCancel(curso : Course) {
        managedObjectContext.deleteObject(curso)
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }


    //MARK: - Segue way

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "addCourseSegue" {
            let nextVc = segue.destinationViewController as! AddCourseViewController
            nextVc.delegate = self

            let selectedCourse = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Course", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Course
            nextVc.course = selectedCourse

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar una tableview necesitas 2 delegados (UITableViewDataSource y UITableViewDelegate) para que el controlador sepa como tiene que hacer la tabla, tendrá que saber cuantas secciones hay, cuantas filas hay por cada sección, etc (tableviewdelegate) y después tendrá que preguntar a alguien (datasourcedelegate) que información poner en cada celda.

Una vez que tienes los datos de alguna manera (Core data, SQLite a las bravas, un array, o como sea) tienes que tener la forma de poder proporcionar a la tabla la información necesaria para que sepa las secciones, las filas por sección y que información va  en cada celda. Si usas Coredata, éste lo hace todo automáticamente, pero si tienes otra fuente de datos te tienes que buscar la vida para proporcinarsela.
El porqué no utilizar tableView.reloadData() y ya está es porque este método lo único que hace es decirle al controlador que vuelva a armar la tabla, así que volverá a llamar a los métodos de numberOfSections, numberOfRows, etc, por lo  que estos métodos hay que implementarlos si o si. Y en principio no deberías llamar al método de reloadData(), al arrancar el controlador ya lo hace él.

El NSFetchResultsController, lo que hace es consultar la BD en SQLite a través de CoreData y se queda manejando los datos y proporcionando los métodos del DataSource que necesitara la tabla. La tabla pregunta y el NSFetchresultcontroller le da la información. El NSFetchresultsController lo configuras para que hága la búsqueda en la entidad que le digas, ordenado de la forma que sea y el se ocupa de todo lo demás. Se ocupa de gestionar la memoria, pedir mas datos, liberar lo que ya no se muestran, acceder a las relaciones, etc.

He mirado el código un poco por encima, y no parece tener "errores", más o menos debería funcionar. Te aconsejo que pongas algún punto de ruptura en los métodos de numberOfSectionsInTableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath y numberOfRowsInSection para comprobar que ahí tienes la información correcta que debería aparecer. Lo mismo tu problema esta en la definición del modelo, tampoco especificas el error que te aparece, dices que no funciona.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. Un problema era que no me mostraba las "rows" de la entidad y ya encontre el problema. Estaba usando      fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects![indexPath.row] as! Course en vez de fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Course